# Passing struct object in function and changing it allocates memory in Julia. Why?

Tags: struct, julia

The code I am playing around with is given below:

```
Base.@kwdef struct cyl_struct
    n::Int64
    a::Array{Float64} =   Array{Float64}(undef,n,2);
end

function adder(cyl)
    for i in 1:cyl.n
        cyl.a[i,1] = 1.0;
    end
end

function adder2(a,n)
    for i in 1:n
        a[i,1] = 1.0;
    end
end

n = 1000;

geom = cyl_struct(n=n);

@btime adder(geom)
@btime adder2(geom.a, geom.n)
```

Running this code gives me the output:

```
  23.700 μs (489 allocations: 7.64 KiB)
  594.444 ns (3 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

My question is: when I pass the structure as argument and make changes inside it, it allocates memory, but when I pass the individual arrays as arguments, it doesn't allocate memory. Why? How can I pass the structure object in a way that it doesn't allocate memory if modified inside function? Please, I would like your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code is replacing the a member of the struct. You can reference the member's elements via a broadcasted assignment instead:

```
using BenchmarkTools

Base.@kwdef struct cyl_struct
    n::Int64
    a::Array{Float64} = Array{Float64}(undef, n, 2);
end

function adder(cyl)
    for i in 1:n
        cyl.a[i, 1] = 1.0
    end
end

function adder1b(cyl)
    cyl.a[1:cyl.n, 1] .= 1.0
end

function adder2(a, n)
    for i in 1:n
        a[i, 1] = 1.0
    end
end

n = 1000
geom = cyl_struct(n = n);

@btime adder(geom)
@btime adder1b(geom)
@btime adder2(geom.a, geom.n)
```

Yields

```
92.600 μs (1979 allocations: 46.56 KiB)
229.712 ns (2 allocations: 96 bytes)
686.755 ns (3 allocations: 80 bytes)
```

Comment: While this seems to solve the problem of assignment and addition, what if I want to use for loop anyway and avoid memory allocation, lets just say for some complex operations that contain if else statements too. How can I pass the structure object in such a way so element-wise operation in loop wouldn't allocate memory?

Comment: I don't use the macro struct declaration idiom you use above, nor do I understand why you appear to initialize your array as 2-D when you don't initially declare it as such (is that how that macro is normally used?). It's possible the compiler is taking some type of incorrect cue from the struct declaration regarding some restriction on how it may mutate the fields of the struct.  I think that you might be better off not using a structure object at all if your structure declarations are so opaque, to me at least.